# How to Display Author Name by AuthorId in DisplayFor helper method

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

In my Book entity class I have AuthorId navigation property. It's used as dataValueField in Selectlist.

```
<!--language:lang-csharp-->
public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public  Author Author { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
```

ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(db.Authors, "Id", "Name");

This is rendered as expected by the means of DropdownList helper inside the form.

```
            <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AuthorId", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control p-0 input-value", id = "input6" })
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <div class="error">
                        <small class="error_form" id="authors_error_message"></small>
                        <div class="icon"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="input6">Authors</label>
                </div>
```

Output:

```
<!--language:lang-html-->
        <select class="form-control p-0 input-value" id="input6" name="AuthorId">
        <option value="1">George R.R. Martin</option>
        <option value="2">James Dashner</option>
        <option value="3">Culian Barns</option>
        </select>
```

I get this Book object in my partial view and use DisplayFor helper to display it in my table but I want it to be displayed as Name not Value

```
<!--language:lang-html-->
@model Project.Entities.Book
<td>
    <p class="wrap-1">@Html.DisplayFor(b => b.AuthorId)</p>
</td>
```

How to do it?

**Update**

As comments below stated it turned out that I should include navigation properties when getting data from database so how to do it properly considering the structure of this action method ? I could include the properties simply by this code :

`var mybook = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == book.Id).Include(a => a.Author).Include(c => c.Category).FirstOrDefault();`

But this could be done only after ModelState validaty is checked being true and book is saved in the database. I would wan to do it before going into `ModelState is valid condition` so that I could check whether the context is filled up with the nested entites before it's saved in the database. How to go about it?

```
<!--language:lang-csharp--> 
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post_AddBook ([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Price,Stock,DateAdded,ISBN,IsApproved,AuthorId,CategoryId")] Book book, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
        {
            book.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0 && (Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName) == ".jpg"))
                {
                    db.Books.Add(book);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Uploads/img/"), book.Id + ".jpg");
                    photo.SaveAs(path);
                    return PartialView(book);
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you getting data from Database, you need `Include` the nested entity like this:

```
context.Books.Where(b=> b.Any()).Include(a => a.Author);
```

Comment: `context.Books.Where(b=> b.Any()).Include(a => a.Author);`  red squiggly line under Any() says `"Book doesn't contain a definition for Any and no extension method Any accepting a first argument of type Book"`  I've edited the question and added ActionMethod. I'd appreciated if you make time to check and revise your answer aftermath

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the AuthorId, so that is what will get displayed. If you want the author name, you should do `b.Author.Name`

Second, it is not a good practice to directly bind the entities to views. You should have a ViewModel in between. Fill up the ViewModel using the entities and only have the required properties/data in your ViewModel, not all entity data. Also, structure your ViewModel in a way that will fit your use case for displaying in View. Bind the ViewModel to the view and not use an entity to display data.

Comment: I bind the required properties in my controller. Also if I use `@Html.DisplayFor(b => b.Author.Name)` i get empty values output in my table under the corresponding columns

Comment: @Cavid It might be because there is lazy loading and the Author navigation property is actually not filled up